# Issue while generating wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm running into issues while generating the WSDL for my service with xml namespaces. Hereis my situation.

I have 3 xsd's and I have generated an object graph out of it. The object, lets say Payload is a parameter for my service call as below:

```
interface IService
{
  bool SendRequest(Payload payload)
}
```

My Payload class has attributes like this:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://company.com/schema/series/2")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Payload", Namespace = "http://company.com/schema/series/2",
            IsNullable = false)]    
public class Payload
{
}
```

Now when I look at my wsdl, it has reference to the c# namespace of the payload class. How can I generate the right wsdl with the accurate schema namespace? This wsdl is given to an externel and the system interopes from a java client.

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
[DataContract(Name="...", Namespace="http://company.com/schema/series/"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark payload as a `DataContract`

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://company.com/schema/series/2")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Payload", Namespace="http://company.com/schema/series/2",IsNullable = false)]   
[DataContract] 
public class Payload
{
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: Actually not sure if I'm answering the question right, is your payload in your WSDL or not?